# How to change background of multiple views in android simultaneously

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created some views in xml which I am using as lines in my application. Every view has the exact same properties.
Example:

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#000" />
```

I want to change the color of all these views simultaneously when the app opens.
Creating ids and then using findviewbyid in java for all of them would not be very efficient. What is the best way to achieve this?
I want them to have the same color all the time.

Comment: `Creating ids and then using findviewbyid in java for all of them would not be very efficient.` why is it not efficient? try using `ListView` and its `divider`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no XML shortcuts in Android for this since you cannot create color changing animations like you described. Now, if you want "efficiency" in terms of clean code while using Java; Take a look at [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), a library that for binding views by using Java annotations in your code. It makes your code very declarative and you can avoid using findViewById, amongst other features.

**Dependencies**

Add to your project build.gradle file;

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

Add to your app module build.gradle file;

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

**In the Activity (or View or Fragment)**

To make Butterknife bind views we'll request it to bind our Activity, onCreate is a good place. Then we'll add fields for Butterknife to bind the views to, in this case as a List of views., although you can also bind the views one by one. Then we'll just change their background for this example.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @BindViews({R.id.view1, R.id.view2, R.id.view3})
    List<View> views;

    public void onCreate(...) {
        ...
        setContentView(...);
        Butterknife.bind(this);

        for(View v : views) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you need to distinguish between the views, instead of having them in a list;

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @BindView(R.id.view1)
    View view1;
    @BindView(R.id.view2)
    View view2;
    @BindView(R.id.view3)
    View view3;

    public void onCreate(...) {
        ...
        setContentView(...);
        Butterknife.bind(this);

        view1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color1));
        view2.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color2));
        view3.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color3));
    }
}
```